# A periodic curve

Tags: calculus, periodic-functions

The graph of the curve $f(x,y)=0$ is formed by infinitely many equal closed curves  as shown in the figure below. Knowing that the distance between two contiguous, vertically and horizontally, of these curves are both equal to $\pi$, is it sufficient   to determine univocally the expression of the function $f$? If yes, what is this expression?

[image]

Comment: As the period is visibly $2 \pi$ in $x$ and $y$, try something like $f(x,y)=\cos(x)\sin(y)=0.3$

Comment: Not at all $cos(x)\sin(y)=0.3$, dear professor. However your perspective could be good.

Comment: Even the wrong ones can be likeable, as they say. Yes there was an inaccuracy, please check the new version.

Comment: Here is an implicit equation which gives a result closer to the given curve(s): $(\sin(x)-1)^2+2.1*\sin(y/2)^2=1.$

Comment: Right dear professor, however "closer to the given curve" is not "the given curve". Mes salutations.

Comment: If f=0 on some region for some f, then if we define g=kf for some constant k, g=0 on the same region, thus there cannot be a unique function that gives these roots.

Comment: There are infinitely many functions $g$ such that $g(x)=0$ in the region where $f(x,y)=0$ but these functions have a graph distinct of the given one.

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment, I fear I do not get the question.
I must be missing something obvious and it is maybe time to go to bed, but I would say the answer to the question as posed ("determine univocally") is trivially negative (which is what worries me).

For example, let us select among all the points $f(x,y) = 0$, one of the closed curves.

We then select the point with highest $y$-coordinate, with lowest, and the same for the $x$-coordinate.

Next  we define a new closed curve $\gamma$, going through these "extreme" (distance defining) points and such that the distance to the lateral and vertical neighbours is unaffected, which is certainly possible (just stay within a square aligned with the axes, going through the "extreme" points).

We then just substitute everywhere the old curves with the new ones, and define the set $\Gamma$ as the union of all periodically translated copies of $\gamma$.
Then we define $g$ as $$
g (x,y) =
\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  0  & \mbox{if } (x,y) \in \Gamma \\
  1 & \mbox{if } (x,y) \notin \Gamma
 \end{array}
\right.
$$

and a new function $g(x,y)$ complies with the same requirements and $g(x,y)=0$ defines different curves. It seems to me that the only requirement of periodicity is far too little.

So what am I missing? Something on how an implicit function is defined?

Comment: Your starting point of choosing "one of the closed curves " could be good but the following (I think) is not.